# What are the assumptions to test on unseen data to use a predictive model?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, validation

I am trying to understand what are the assumptions I have to test, to use a predictive model on unseen data. After the validation phase of my predictive model and the estimation of its accuracy on a test set, I would like to understand on what kind of similar data I can use my model. Is there any rule to respect? I couldn`t find anything in the literature. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Statistical assumption when you use methods from statistics could be to assume that process which generated your train/dev/valid data sets is similar in scoring data set to which your newly developed model is applied.

This is actual example from my work:

We sampled source population to get an sample of N leads. These were called by telephone and their response was surveyed. Next several variables were joined to this list and I modeled this outcome (response variable) as a function of these variables. At next step population was split into sub-groups of those potential and those not based on estimated probability of certain class of response variable.

After that optimized telephone campaign was conducted and it was seen that results were mostly expected.

Key fact here was that population was known and we had an stratified sampling scheme to present all interesting combinations of certain variables.